# JQuery inline dialog?

Tags: jquery

The built in JQuery dialog is a great widget for organizing content.  How do I make it inline so that I can have a bunch of dialog all in the same parent div right next to each other?  I basically want to use it to organize my content.

Comment: You don't have to have two separate dialogs to organise the data inside a dialog, you could just split a single dialog in to two.  Using two `<div>`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to have two separate dialogs to organise the data inside a dialog, you could just split a single dialog in to two by floating two divs together.

CSS:

```
div#dialogDiv {  }
div#dialogDiv div.div_left { float: left; width: 200px; height: 200px; }
div#dialogDiv div.div_right { float: left; width: 200px; height: 200px; }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="dialogDiv">
    <div class="div_left">left content</div>
    <div class="div_right">right content</div>
</div>
```